# Adding /home directory to the existing user in linux

Tags: linux, centos7

The below mentioned code is not working properly (CentOS 7/bash file code):

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /etc/passwd | egrep -v '^(root|halt|sync|shutdown)' |
awk -F: '($7 != "/sbin/nologin" && $7 != "/bin/false") { print $1 " " $6 }' |
while read user dir; do
   if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then
      echo "The home directory ($dir) of user $user does not exist."
   fi
done
```

The code written here is going in infinite loop.
Can you please tell me what to do?

Comment: Works as expected for me on Fedora 33. Other than the UUOC, the script looks OK.

Comment: `bash -x` your_script might give you some hints what's happening in the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has already been suggested, there is an unnecessary use of cat into grep and then an unnecessary pipe of grep into awk. You can condense the execution with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F: '$1 !~ /root|halt|sync|shutdown/ && $7 != "/sbin/nologin" && $7 != "/bin/false" 
{ print $1 " " $6 }' /etc/passwd | while read user dir;
do
 if [[ ! -d "$dir" ]];
 then
     echo "The home directory ($dir) of user $user does not exist."
 fi
done
```